# Need an xpath to lookup an attribute value by that attribute's name as a string

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt, xslt-1.0

Using an xslt 1.0 xpath I would like to provide the name of an attribute as an xs:string and compare it's value against a constant.

given

```
<School>
   <classroom number=101 male="0" female="13"/>
   <classroom number=202 male="0" female="23"/>
   <classroom number=303 male="0" female="31"/>

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="//@*[name()='male' or name()='female']">
    <variable name="gender_null_truth" select="count(//classroom[@*[name(.)]/value() &gt; 0]) = 0"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('It is ', $gender_null_truth, ' that the school has no ',name(.)'s '/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:match="/">
     <xsl:template apply-templates select="School/classroom/@males" />
     <xsl:template apply-templates select="School/classroom/@females" />
</xsl:match>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

output:

```
It is true that the school has no males
It is false that the school has no females
```

Pls ignore trivial errors. The issue I am having is building an expression that will do this:

```
//classroom[@*[name(.)]/value() &gt; 0]
```

that is, essentially convert the string name of an attribute to an attribute that I can query the value of. Would prefer an xpath but, I'm not averse to using keysI didn't have much luck with those either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that the question is not clear.

Looking purely at what seems to be the expected output, I wonder if the following example could be useful to you:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/School">
    <results>
        <xsl:call-template name="verify">
            <xsl:with-param name="attr-name">male</xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:call-template name="verify">
            <xsl:with-param name="attr-name">female</xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
   </results>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="verify">
    <xsl:param name="attr-name"/>
    <xsl:variable name="sum" select="sum(classroom/@*[name()=$attr-name])" />
    <result>
        <xsl:text>It is </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="not($sum)"/>
        <xsl:text> that the school has no </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$attr-name"/>
        <xsl:text>s.</xsl:text>
    </result>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I run this against the input of:

```
<School>
   <classroom number="101" male="0" female="13"/>
   <classroom number="202" male="0" female="23"/>
   <classroom number="303" male="0" female="31"/>
</School>
```

I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<results>
   <result>It is true that the school has no males.</result>
   <result>It is false that the school has no females.</result>
</results>
```

Of course, there is a simpler way to get such result. But it seems your question is how to summarize the values of an attribute whose name is given as a string, and this shows a way.

Comment: The sum is a good approach.

I'm getting feedback the question isn't clear. The point is to avoid making two templates for processing attributes that are so similar that operations on their values within their templates are identical. Instead, make one template that does the same operation on both.

To speak to where I am stumped. 

If I can speak by way of analogy, if an attribute referenced by it's name(.) is 'dynamic', how does one retrieve the value of a 'dynamic' attribute?
Attributes have a name() function, is there something like a "value()" function?

Comment: I am afraid you have lost me at this point (if I wasn't lost right from the beginning). In the given example, you could make a template that matches `"@male | @female"` to process both attributes. However, such template will process each matched attribute individually; it won't sum the values of **all** matched attributes.

Comment: If you need a function that processes two or more node-sets in a similar way, then a named template, like in my example, is the tool to use (in XSLT 1.0). But there is no need to go through a string to specify the node-set; you can send the selected node-set directly as the parameter.